# Is Groovy supposed to allow a comma to separate assertion message?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, the below produces the error message seen, just like Java would (apart from the different quotes and missing semicolon)

```
assert false : 'If you see me, colons are allowed!'
```

This also products the error message, but a comma is separating the message from the Boolean expression

```
assert false, 'If you see me, commas are allowed!'
```

I can't find anything about this in the Groovy documentation, is this correct behavior?

You can try this on the [Groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/).

---

I'm not asking if it *does* allow commas, clearly it seems to, but I'm wondering if I have missed something in the documentation, this is a bug, or if it's just undocumented.

Comment: There are some samples in the documentation - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#groovy-operators

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are valid, as you can see in the [antlr grammar file for Groovy](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/3879511e3a8ae66c8045edb32cb37f12fae02a1b/src/main/antlr2/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g#L1883-L1884)

```
|   "assert"! assertAle: assignmentLessExpression!
    (   options {greedy=true;} :
        (   COMMA! nls! // TODO:  gratuitous change caused failures
        |   COLON! nls! // standard Java syntax, but looks funny in Groovy
        )
        assertE:expression[0]!
    )?
```

The comma syntax seems to have been added because the colon syntax (of Java) looks funny in Groovy.